# Piping input AND output of ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to create a video, from a list of base64 encoded images that I pipe into `ffmpeg`.

Outputting to a file (using the attached code below) works perfectly, but what I would like to achieve is to get the output to a Python variable instead - meaning piping input and piping output but I can't seem to get it to work

My current code:

```
output = os.path.join(screenshots_dir, 'video1.mp4')

cmd_out = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',  # (optional) overwrite output file if it exists
           '-f', 'image2pipe',
           '-vcodec', 'png',
           '-r', str(fps),  # frames per second
           '-i', '-',  # The input comes from a pipe
           '-vcodec', 'png',
           '-qscale', '0',
           output]

pipe = sp.Popen(cmd_out, stdin=sp.PIPE)

for screenshot in screenshot_list:
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(screenshot)))
    im.save(pipe.stdin, 'PNG')

pipe.stdin.close()
pipe.wait()
```

This results in a working mp4, but I would like to avoid saving to local.

Running the same code with changing `output` to `'-'` or `'pipe:1'` and adding `stdout=sp.PIPE` results in an error

> [NULL @ 0x2236000] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg guesses the output muxer by checking the output extension. With a pipe, that doesn't exist, so it has to be expressly set. Add `'-f', 'image2pipe'` just before output.

Comment: Can't help you with the python part. Only ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for that anyway, for now seems to be working. I'll see if I indeed catch it and verify it is the video, if so I will accept

Comment: Seems that it gets stuck forever on the `Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> png (native)) part

Comment: Need to see full ffmpeg console.

Comment: Has your input terminated?

Comment: It is stuck like that forever

Comment: exact same output

Comment: The logfile will have more details. Need to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following command after your `sp.Popen` :

```
output, _ = pipe.communicate()
```

I think you need to communicate it with the opened process. After that you can print it to make sure it worked :

```
print(_)
```